# Issues with boost::multi_index

Tags: c++, boost, multi-index, boost-multi-index

When I try to create a object of this,

```
typedef boost::multi_index_container<
ClassX*,                                                                                    //mapped value
boost::multi_index::indexed_by<                                                 //list of indices    
    boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<                                                          
        boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<ParentClassOfX, Key1, &ParentClassOfX::getKey1>               //hashed index by unique Key1
    >,
    boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<           
        boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<ParentClassOfX, Vs64, &ParentClassOfX::getKey2>               //hashed index by unique Key1
    >
>
>ClassXMultiKeyIndexed;
```

like,

```
ClassXMultiKeyIndexed sample;
```

and insert a pointer like this,

```
ClassX *a;
ClassXMultiKeyIndexed sample;

//a is not NULL and is filled up before the below insert
sample.insert(a);
```

This is the compilation error, it compiles fine if "sample.insert(a)" is commented out.

Compilation error :

```
Compiling...
.
.
.
xtyab.cpp
c:\code\common\lib\boost\boost\detail\allocator_utilities.hpp(153) : error     C2061: syntax error : identifier 'p'
            c:\code\common\lib\boost\boost\multi_index\detail\index_base.hpp(105) : see     reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::detail::allocator::construct<Container*>(void *,const Type &)' being compiled
    with
    [
        Type=Container *
    ]
    c:\code\common\lib\boost\boost\multi_index\detail\index_base.hpp(102) : while compiling class template member function 'boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_index_node<Super,Category> *boost::multi_index::detail::index_base<Value,IndexSpecifierList,Allocator>::insert_(Container *const &,boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_index_node<Super,Category> *&,boost::multi_index::detail::lvalue_tag)'
    with
    [
        Super=boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<Container *,std::allocator<Container *>>,boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_unique_tag>,
        Category=boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_unique_tag,
        Value=Container *,
        IndexSpecifierList=boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<DBObject,Key1,DBObject::getKey1>>,boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<DBObject,Vs64,DBObject::getKey2>>>,
        Allocator=std::allocator<Container *>
    ]
    c:\code\common\lib\boost\boost\multi_index\hashed_index.hpp(93) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::multi_index::detail::index_base<Value,IndexSpecifierList,Allocator>' being compiled
    with
    [
        Value=Container *,
        IndexSpecifierList=boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<DBObject,Key1,DBObject::getKey1>>,boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<DBObject,Vs64,DBObject::getKey2>>>,
        Allocator=std::allocator<Container *>
    ]
    c:\code\common\lib\boost\boost\multi_index\hashed_index.hpp(93) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_index<KeyFromValue,Hash,Pred,SuperMeta,TagList,Category>' being compiled
    with
    [
        KeyFromValue=boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<DBObject,Vs64,DBObject::getKey2>,
        Hash=boost::hash<boost::long_long_type>,
        Pred=std::equal_to<__int64>,
        SuperMeta=boost::multi_index::detail::nth_layer<2,Container *,boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<DBObject,Key1,DBObject::getKey1>>,boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<DBObject,Vs64,DBObject::getKey2>>>,std::allocator<Container *>>,
        TagList=boost::mpl::vector0<boost::mpl::na>,
        Category=boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_unique_tag
    ]
    c:\code\common\lib\boost\boost\multi_index_container.hpp(100) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_index<KeyFromValue,Hash,Pred,SuperMeta,TagList,Category>' being compiled
    with
    [
        KeyFromValue=boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<DBObject,Key1,DBObject::getKey1>,
        Hash=boost::hash<boost::long_long_type>,
        Pred=std::equal_to<__int64>,
        SuperMeta=boost::multi_index::detail::nth_layer<1,Container *,boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<DBObject,Key1,DBObject::getKey1>>,boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<DBObject,Vs64,DBObject::getKey2>>>,std::allocator<Container *>>,
        TagList=boost::mpl::vector0<boost::mpl::na>,
        Category=boost::multi_index::detail::hashed_unique_tag
    ]
    c:\code\common\src\biz\model\stm-stow_model\stm_container_manager_abc.h(323) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<Value,IndexSpecifierList>' being compiled
    with
    [
        Value=Container *,
        IndexSpecifierList=boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<DBObject,Key1,DBObject::getKey1>>,boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<DBObject,Vs64,DBObject::getKey2>>>
    ]
Build log was saved at "file://c:\code\win\Debug\obj\BuildLog.htm"
ProjABC - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The compiler points to boost
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not a snippet with unknowable classes.

Comment: The syntax error is where you type `p` and the compiler doesn't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `c:\code\common\lib\boost\boost\detail\allocator_utilities.hpp(153) : error     C2061: syntax error : identifier 'p'` implies you modified boost sources, probably unwittingly.

Comment: @Ram To be sure, compile an empty source file with just `#include <boost/detail/allocator_utilities.hpp>`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: That might not prove anything since templates aren't instantiated until used.

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely to be an issue with boost multi-index container, you've not given too much detail, but the following code is based on your approach and should compile fine. Try it on your compiler - and once you've proved to yourself, then compare what is different and fix that.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/mem_fun.hpp>

using boost::multi_index_container;
using boost::multi_index::indexed_by;
using boost::multi_index::hashed_unique;
using boost::multi_index::tag;

using namespace std;

struct foo {
    int id_a;
    int id_b;
    int get_id_a() const {
        return id_a;
    }
    int get_id_b() const {
        return id_b;
    }
};

struct tag_a {};
struct tag_b {};

using foo_container = boost::multi_index_container<
foo*,
indexed_by<
  hashed_unique<tag<tag_a>, BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_CONST_MEM_FUN(foo, int, get_id_a)>,
  hashed_unique<tag<tag_b>, BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_CONST_MEM_FUN(foo, int, get_id_b)>
>
>;

int main() {
    foo_container c;
    foo f1{1, 2};
    foo f2{2, 3};
    c.insert(&f1);
    c.insert(&f2);

    {
        auto it = c.get<tag_a>().find(1);
        if (it != c.get<tag_a>().end()) {
            cout << (*it)->id_a << ' ' << (*it)->id_b << endl;
        }
    }
    {
        auto it = c.get<tag_b>().find(3);
        if (it != c.get<tag_b>().end()) {
            cout << (*it)->id_a << ' ' << (*it)->id_b << endl;
        }
    }    
}
```